# How can I identify a marker in mapview?

Tags: android

I am using MapView in my application, Which contains several markers of different users.I want to update user location.What i tried is, i remove and add all these markers when i get a new user location.Is there any way to identify the marker which i add for a particular user among all other markers ?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is set the `Snippet` to a JSON string representation(using Google's GSON library) of any object which references or identifies the marker.  When the marker is tapped, i use GSON to get my object back.

```
String snippet = new Gson().toJson(myObject);
//use snippet with your overlay item
```

for your `onTap(int index)` method:

```
OverlayItem item = overlays.get(index);
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(item.getSnippet(), MyObject.class);
```

This all assumes that you have an object you can serialize/deserialize

GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

You can give the markers title and snippets. In your case you can give each user a title or each marker can be given a unique user ID as the snippet property. Then you can retrieve these by the `getTitle()` and `getSnippet()` method of the overlay items(your markers).
Refer the [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem.html#mSnippet) form more on title and snippet.
Hope this helped.